# 503 Service Unavailable - EC-2 / WordPress with NGINX and SSL Certified by Bitnami-4-9-8-1-r40

Tags: wordpress, nginx, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have been trying to learn AWS EC-2 and installing WordPress by Bitnami. I was planning to move all my sites from cPanel to AWS in the future if I could pull this off.

I am having issues with constantly getting 503 Unavailable Error when I attached the Amazon Issued SSL.

I was able to create an Instance, Certificate, DNS via Route 53, Load Balancer, Security Group and Target successfully I just can't get the site up. :(

Public IP works though 54.237.218.136

What could go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

503 gateway time out it is. well your configuration and services need a restart , As Amazon provided Certificate works with Load Balancer (Application or Classic)
503 is the gateway time out from php-fpm or Apache 2 As you haven't shared the logs to give you a more prise solution I would suggest to login on your EC2-Wordpress powered by Bitnami and run the following commands .

sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status

sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop

sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start

Please follow this document as well: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/control-services/
I'm sure that committed changes with the configuration has not been loaded yet as your EC2 is even not responding on this IP ,
I'm sure about the Load Balancer and certificate is not the problem here.

You can ping me if you need help with this it's not a really tough job.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Prabhat, I ended up redoing everything. The site is up now and I was installing SSL and followed every step in https://www.davidmeents.com/add-ssl-ec2-wordpress-instance-use-https/. I am getting an invalid certificate and it was issued to a wildcard domain from Amazon. Load Balancers are healthy as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, Firstly let me know if you are using Application load balancer or Classic because the step you are following is for the classic one .

Comment: Now regardless of the domain if the Certificate Authority approved it , it will start working Did you check the Route 53 whether a new record set is created automatically or not for the certificate ?

Comment: Hi Prabhat, i followed your guidance and finally fixed it. I was using Classic LB. The security group settings were incorrect. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I started getting 503 errors very frequently with the WordPress certified by bitnami stack (apache) earlier in 2023. After much head scratching, I finally identified Updraft Plus as the culprit. After moving my site's backup processes to use "All in One Migration", the crashes stopped and my sites work as expected again.